# Significance test for comparing different 10-fold cross-validated Machine Learning Regressions

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, predictive-models, model-comparison

Is there a recommended significance test for comparing different 10-fold cross validated regressions?

For instance, I want to compare the performance of LASSO against Random Forest for my dataset.

1. Both models are then evaluated using 10-fold cross validation.
2. Within each cross-validatoin, each one produces a different model,
3. Each model is compared against the test fold. Each test fold therefore has ***N / 10*** comparisons.
4. Aggregating across the different models, I get ***N*** predictions, each of which I can then compare the ***ŷ*** against the ***y*** to see evaluate model accuracy.
5. If I square this differnce, This gives me ***(ŷ-y)^2***, or the squared errors for each observation.
6. If i compare the mean of ***(ŷ-y)^2*** for a modeling approach (LASSO vs RF), the i effectively get the MSE for each approach for my data
7. **Normally, I would just select the model approach with the best MSE, and use that. Is there a way to test the significance between the two modeling approaches to confirm if one is producing a significantly lower MSE than the other?**

My intuition is to run a paired-samples t-test on the ***(ŷ-y)^2*** between the two methods. However, if that works as a test, won't running repeated cross-validations (and thus leading to an unlimited ***N*** mean that every comparison of models is infinitely good if you are as long as you run enough cross-validatoin repetitoins?

Also, what would I do if I wanted to compare a model tested on a 10-fold cross validated set against one that was tested on a 4-fold cross validated set (the 4-fold set is due to having 4 sites in a trial, and doing site-wise cross validation). In this case, the 10-fold cross validation can be repeated an unlimited times, since it is resampling. But the 4-fold is confine so the site-wise cross validation cannot be resample dan infinite number of times.

If I run a paired-samples t-test across a model run in the 10-fold vs the 4-fold to see accuracy, does it ruin the assumptions of the t-test?

Comment: This does not address the details of your question, but [Diebold-Mariano test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/diebold-mariano-test/info) may be a relevant tool.

Comment: I'm avoiding the Deibold-Mariano specifically because the author of it says it's not for comparing models.

"The Diebold–Mariano (DM) test was intended for comparing forecasts; it has been, and remains, useful in that regard. The DM test was not intended for comparing models. " https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236

Comment: Can I just run a Wilcoxon T-test between the squared errors of the two different modelling approaches? My qualm with that is: if it's just a simple t-test, can't you endlessly inflate the sampel size by running more repeated cross validations, therefore always proving that they are significantly different?

Comment: Then if you follow the same paper, you should find some suggestions of how to do that in other ways that do not use the DM test. Regarding Wilcoxon t-test, I suspect the argument against the use of the DM test applies to the Wilcoxon t-test, too.

Comment: Thanks but those methods don't address the main issue with the repeated cross-validation MSE: Since i can repeatedly repeat cross validations with new samples each time, doesn't this allow endlessly inflating the sample?

Comment: Repeated cross validation results in dependent observations, so the effective count of data points is not increasing. You could just as well replicate every observation 1000 times, but that would still keep the effective number of data points unchanged.

Comment: Hmmm okay I've gone back in and tried playing around with the Diebold-Mariano test. The way I've applied it is to pull out the squared errors of the two competing models, and then input them into the test. But what is odd is that I can't seem to find a way to adapt it to the repeated cross validations inflating the sample size. Any suggestions?

Comment: Compare your models on an independent test set. Folds from cross validation are not suited for that if you have been training or tuning your models on them.

Comment: I don't have a test, so no answer. But IMHO we need to take into account that there are (at least) two separate sources of variance here: random uncertainty due to the actual number of indepent test cases (which does not increase with repetitions), and random uncertainty due to model (in)stability, for which each new surrogate model gives a new data point.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX, yet we have to take into account that these new data points are not independent if the model is estimated on partly the same data in every new case.

Comment: @RichardHardy: that aspect of independence IMHO depends crucially on the purpose of the modeling. I'm in an applied field, i.e. I compare models in order to obtain *a particular* model that shoudl then go into application use. Thus the focus is the performance of models derived *from the particular data set at hand*.  As opposed to comparing training algorithms for a given problem, where the data set at hand is only one (not very particular) sample of the application data population. Thus, I take the view that cross validation resampling yields (slightly) perturbed versions of "my" data, ...

Comment: ... so very far from assuming that cross validation resampling simulates new samples of the same size from the original population. If the latter is needed, there is no way to estimate the related variance from within a resampling experiment such as (repeated) cross validation. In the former case, we only need the uncertainty Δperformance/ΔCV-related-change-in-training-sample. But OP needs to specify the purpose of their comparison.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX, I think I get that, and that is an intricate topic. I have a hunch that my concerns still apply, but I cannot prove that (even to myself) without going into detail of considerable depth.

Comment: @Richard Hardy
Models are trained and validated on an internal cross validation loop. So the data is sorted out like this:
100 people --> 90 "training + validaiton data" + 10 testing data. Then
90 Training+validation data -> 81 Training + 9 validation x10 cross validaiton to tune each model and end up with 1 final model each.

this gives 10 different models built on 90 samples, each tested once each on 10 different test sets.

Comment: I do this entire process for both LASSO/Random Forest/SVM a few other methods. So I end up with 10 measures of cross vadliated test accuracy for each. So can I compare across the different methods of LASSO/RF/SVM, given that each have 10 cross-validated tested accuracies? especially since I could repeat the process multiple times to get even more measurements of accuracy.

@cbeleites unhappy with SX. The goal is to significance test whether LASSO/RandomForest/SVM does better at producing models, in general, for this dataset.

Comment: @RichardHardy The tricky part is i'm not sure how doing 10 differen test sets of 10 observations each is any different from one single test set of 10 observations. If anything, it should be more stable. Models are completely blind to the test set each time, so it's as if i'm doing the 10 independent test sets 10 times.

Comment: @orangelemontree, I guess it should work OK if you do this once. But if you repeat the process multiple times, you will be reusing the same observations of the test sets in each repetition, so your effective sample size in the Diebold-Mariano test will not increase beyond what you have in a single repetition. So you should either just do one repetition or if you do many then adjust the sample size (in the formula for the test statistic or in the formula for the critical values) to the size of one repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the situation:

> won't running repeated cross-validations (and thus leading to an unlimited N mean that every comparison of models is infinitely good if you are as long as you run enough cross-validatoin repetitoins?

no, because (whatever test you decide to use), you need to adjust the degrees of freedom according to the actual number of independent test (in the CV sense) cases you have. Which does not increase with the repetitions, since no new cases enter the procedure.

In the CV situation there are several distinct sources of variance. In particular

- the (finite, limited) number of independent cases that are ever used as test case during the CV.
  This cannot increase beyond the number of cases that you encounter within a repetition of the CV. It may anyways be quite smaller than the number of data rows if you have dependence there e.g. because of repeated or nearly repeated measurements.
- Model instability: The variance in true performance between the CV surrogate models. Repetitions help to get a better assessment of this.

Now, there are two different scenarios for which such model comparisons are frequently used:

1. A model is built from the data set at hand for application use and its performance for production use is to estimated, e.g. in order so choose the best between a bunch of such models.
2. Model training algorithms are to be compared for a particular application domain. The crucial difference is that here we want to estimate the performance of the training algorithm for similar, but new data sets. So the training data set at hand is only one example/instance/sample.

For cross validation, those two scenarios make different assumptions:

Scenario 1 assumes that all surrogate models are equivalent to the production use model that is trained on the whole data set at hand. This assumption is often not met: the surrogate models are a bit worse due to having fewer training cases. And the surrogate models may not even be equivalent to each other. We can measure/estimate the variance between the performance of the surrogate models, though via the cross validation. We may that variance as approximation for the additional uncertainty wrt. the performance of the model derived from the whole data set. Note that the selection decision would not change with a constant bias across the considered algorithms.

Scenario 2 in contrast makes a *far* more dangerous assumption by taking re-samples that cannot differ by more than 2/k from each other as approximations of entirely new samples. Variance observed in the surrogate models is therefore a rather bad approximation for the actual variance needed to judge significance.

---

At the moment, I cannot provide you with a suitable significance test that accounts for these different sources of variance.

However, there are two situations where we can draw conclusions:

- If you are in situation 1, and the surrogate models are stable, i.e. variance in surrogate model performance << variance due to finite test sample size, you may neglect the former and proceed with a pairwise test using only the latter variance.
  A limitation is that the pessimistic bias of the cross validation may not be constant across the different training algorithms - and this is not taken into account.
  (If the situation is the opposite, the conclusion would be that you need to improve = stabilize the training rather than moving on to production use)
- If performance does not differ significantly under scenario 1, it cannot possibly be significant under scenario 2, neither, since scenario 2 is subject to additional variance uncertainty.